# How to implements native UI inLocoMedia react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I've the following code:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(context);
adView.setType(AdType.DISPLAY_BANNER_SMALL);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.setAdUnitId(<Your Ad Unit>);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
parent.addView(adView);
```

That create a programmatically Android View, and I need to display it in a js side, like:

```
<View>
  // This tag will work like a Android View programmatically in your back.
  <AdView />
</View>
```

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your own wrapper to the native UI.

See official docs for [Native UI Component for Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html)

And this can help too [Native Modules for Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html)